# How to format time since xxx e.g. “4 minutes ago” similar to Stack Exchange sites

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

The question is how to format a JavaScript `Date` as a string stating the time elapsed similar to the way you see times displayed on Stack Overflow.

e.g.

- 1 minute ago
- 1 hour ago
- 1 day ago
- 1 month ago
- 1 year ago

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: https://github.com/catamphetamine/javascript-time-ago

Comment: Useful for this: [**`Intl.RelativeTimeFormat.prototype.format()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RelativeTimeFormat/format).

Comment: `Moment` is deprecated, it is a legacy project in maintenance mode. Switch to built-in `Intl.RelativeTimeFormat` in javascript or use other alternatives.

Comment: Since there is no native way to do this, IMO this is the same as asking for an external library, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It would be an honor for you to use my [tiny script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yaireo/relative-time) `0.5kb`

Answer (score 484):

```js
function timeSince(date) {

  var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);

  var interval = seconds / 31536000;

  if (interval > 1) {
    return Math.floor(interval) + " years";
  }
  interval = seconds / 2592000;
  if (interval > 1) {
    return Math.floor(interval) + " months";
  }
  interval = seconds / 86400;
  if (interval > 1) {
    return Math.floor(interval) + " days";
  }
  interval = seconds / 3600;
  if (interval > 1) {
    return Math.floor(interval) + " hours";
  }
  interval = seconds / 60;
  if (interval > 1) {
    return Math.floor(interval) + " minutes";
  }
  return Math.floor(seconds) + " seconds";
}
var aDay = 24*60*60*1000;
console.log(timeSince(new Date(Date.now()-aDay)));
console.log(timeSince(new Date(Date.now()-aDay*2)));
```

Comment: @hello - yeah, single point of exit has it's virtues when it doesn't get in the way. those that take it too seriously these days are misunderstanding the origin of the maxim.

Comment: Good function, but some remarks. Changed the first line to:  var seconds = Math.floor(((new Date().getTime()/1000) - date)) to work with unix timestamps. And needed to change the intval > 1 to intval >=1 otherwise it would show things like 75 minutes (between 1 and 2 hours).

Comment: @PanMan if you just change > to >= then you will end up with times like "1 minutes". I posted a modified version of this answer that conditionally adds the "s": http://stackoverflow.com/a/23259289/373655

Comment: Never use string concatenation, but String.format if you want a solution that can be internationalized

Comment: What if I want to place it in div class? What can I do? Sorry I'm not a pro in javascript. I tried this

document.getElementsByTagName('.sampleclass')[0].innerHTML = timeSince(date);  and this

document.getElementById('idname')[0].innerHTML = timeSince(date);

but it's not working. Any help? Thank you.

Comment: @PanMan still facing some issue, when I'm using this function, it returns 63 secs instead of 1 min, 26 hours instead of 1 day.

Comment: @SkySanders can you please let me know how can I resolve above issue?

Comment: If I needed to mainly display fresh content, I would rewrite this function to have it in reverse order (to avoid useless calculations, floor() calls and ifs).

Comment: how to calculate future date and time ..like In 5 Days or 3Hrs

Comment: Additionally, one could add `> 2` at all levels to achieve  `plural hours, days, months, etc` like this: `interval = seconds / 86400;
  if (interval > 2) {return Math.floor(interval) + " days";` and `interval = seconds / 86400;
  if (interval > 1) {return Math.floor(interval) + " day";`

Comment: This fails to account for plurals and will return "1 minutes ago", "1 hours ago". My answer accounts for plurals https://stackoverflow.com/a/72973090/3494595

Comment: @SkySanders this code is fine except: The Problem with this way of calculating the interval will return wrong data at some point because you are not expecting possible time deviations caused by leap years or semi-annual timeshifts.
I will post an additinal answer soon to address this problem.

Answer (score 206):

Might be an overkill in this case, but if the opportunity shows [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is just awesome!

Moment.js is a javascript datetime library, to use it for such scenario, you'd do:

```
moment(yourdate).fromNow()
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

**2018 addendum**: [Luxon](http://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) is a new modern library and might be worth a look!

**2022 addendum**: [Day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/from-now) is a newer library that's about 80% lighter than Luxon with similar capabilities.

Comment: Hello, I am using your answer for getting time differene.What can I do if I need only first letters of datelike year as y, month and m and day as d?

Comment: how do I only get D M s h and not days ago months ago using  this?

Comment: Not overkill if you already have moment installed. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently this is outdated and slow.

Comment: The equivalent Luxon method is [toRelativeCalendar](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetorelativecalendar)

Answer (score 83):

This will show you past and previous time formats like '2 days ago' '10 minutes from now' and you can pass it either a Date object, a numeric timestamp or a date string

```js
function time_ago(time) {

  switch (typeof time) {
    case 'number':
      break;
    case 'string':
      time = +new Date(time);
      break;
    case 'object':
      if (time.constructor === Date) time = time.getTime();
      break;
    default:
      time = +new Date();
  }
  var time_formats = [
    [60, 'seconds', 1], // 60
    [120, '1 minute ago', '1 minute from now'], // 60*2
    [3600, 'minutes', 60], // 60*60, 60
    [7200, '1 hour ago', '1 hour from now'], // 60*60*2
    [86400, 'hours', 3600], // 60*60*24, 60*60
    [172800, 'Yesterday', 'Tomorrow'], // 60*60*24*2
    [604800, 'days', 86400], // 60*60*24*7, 60*60*24
    [1209600, 'Last week', 'Next week'], // 60*60*24*7*4*2
    [2419200, 'weeks', 604800], // 60*60*24*7*4, 60*60*24*7
    [4838400, 'Last month', 'Next month'], // 60*60*24*7*4*2
    [29030400, 'months', 2419200], // 60*60*24*7*4*12, 60*60*24*7*4
    [58060800, 'Last year', 'Next year'], // 60*60*24*7*4*12*2
    [2903040000, 'years', 29030400], // 60*60*24*7*4*12*100, 60*60*24*7*4*12
    [5806080000, 'Last century', 'Next century'], // 60*60*24*7*4*12*100*2
    [58060800000, 'centuries', 2903040000] // 60*60*24*7*4*12*100*20, 60*60*24*7*4*12*100
  ];
  var seconds = (+new Date() - time) / 1000,
    token = 'ago',
    list_choice = 1;

  if (seconds == 0) {
    return 'Just now'
  }
  if (seconds < 0) {
    seconds = Math.abs(seconds);
    token = 'from now';
    list_choice = 2;
  }
  var i = 0,
    format;
  while (format = time_formats[i++])
    if (seconds < format[0]) {
      if (typeof format[2] == 'string')
        return format[list_choice];
      else
        return Math.floor(seconds / format[2]) + ' ' + format[1] + ' ' + token;
    }
  return time;
}

var aDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
console.log(time_ago(new Date(Date.now() - aDay)));
console.log(time_ago(new Date(Date.now() - aDay * 2)));
```

Comment: Replace the last line `return time;` with `format = time_formats[time_formats.length - 1];
return Math.floor(seconds / format[2]) + ' ' + format[1] + ' ' + token;` to return centuries for large time spans instead of the milliseconds.

Comment: Very nice! Though I noticed in iOS, when used with angular as a filter, the browser returns NaN here. This fixes it:  
time = +new Date(time.replace(/-/g, '/'));

Comment: Great, but the assignment in that while loop is ugly and confusing. Changing to a forEach loop would be better

Comment: I was having an issue where I wasn't able to see 'Just now', and kept getting 0 seconds ago.  So I changed the line to `if (seconds < 1) {
    return 'Just now'
  }`
which resolved my issue

Comment: can you explain why "while (format = time_formats[i++])"

Answer (score 60):

I haven't checked (although it wouldn't be hard to), but I think that **Stack Exchange sites use the [`jquery.timeago` plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) to create these time strings**.

---

It's quite easy to use the plugin, and it's clean and updates automatically.

Here's a quick sample (from the plugin's home page):

> First, load jQuery and the plugin:
>
> `<script src="jquery.min.js"
>   type="text/javascript"></script>
>   <script src="jquery.timeago.js"
>   type="text/javascript"></script>`
>
> Now, let's attach it to your
>   timestamps on DOM ready:
>
> `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
>
>   jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago(); });`
>
> This will turn all `abbr` elements
>   with a class of `timeago` and an ISO
>   8601 timestamp in the title: `<abbr
>   class="timeago"
>   title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17,
>   2008</abbr>` into something like this:
>   `<abbr class="timeago" title="July 17,
>   2008">about a year ago</abbr>` which
>   yields: about a year ago. As time
>   passes, the timestamps will
>   automatically update.

Comment: Not everybody uses JQuery.

Comment: Makes no sense to have this as a jquery plugin.

Answer (score 37):

Yet another take on `Intl.RelativeTimeFormat`

- Supports both past and future dates
- Accepts both `String` and `Date`
- Custom ranges are easy to add (edit `ranges`)
- Can be easily translated `Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('ua')`

```js
console.log(timeAgo('2021-08-09T15:29:01+0000'));

function timeAgo(input) {
  const date = (input instanceof Date) ? input : new Date(input);
  const formatter = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('en');
  const ranges = {
    years: 3600 * 24 * 365,
    months: 3600 * 24 * 30,
    weeks: 3600 * 24 * 7,
    days: 3600 * 24,
    hours: 3600,
    minutes: 60,
    seconds: 1
  };
  const secondsElapsed = (date.getTime() - Date.now()) / 1000;
  for (let key in ranges) {
    if (ranges[key] < Math.abs(secondsElapsed)) {
      const delta = secondsElapsed / ranges[key];
      return formatter.format(Math.round(delta), key);
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tv9701uf

**UPDATE**
For TypeScript usage please also consider the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72817357/2619961

Comment: A very clear solution using modern APIs. Beautiful.

Comment: Please publish this as a `npm` package - including TypeScript declarations!

Comment: Sure, will do that in my spare time, glad it came in handy

Comment: Yep this is very clean and beautiful code ! well done

Comment: cannot translate into myanmar (burma) . how can I do this , to support in Myanmar language. Currently I replace string like this
day = ရက်

Comment: @ThanHtutZaw Perhaps you could configure it as follows: new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('my');

Comment: I tried , when I try Kr-ko , I got Korean . But I don't get myanmar date . If they are not supported , how to contribute or changes to support this language.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it doesn't work with Myanmar properly for some reason, I suspect it's due to browser implementation :(

Comment: To make this typescript friendly, just add `as keyof typeof ranges` to cast `key` to the thing typescript is being an idiot about.

Answer (score 32):

Here is a slight modification on Sky Sander's solution that allows the date to be input as a string and is capable of displaying spans like "1 minute" instead of "73 seconds"

```js
var timeSince = function(date) {
  if (typeof date !== 'object') {
    date = new Date(date);
  }

  var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);
  var intervalType;

  var interval = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
  if (interval >= 1) {
    intervalType = 'year';
  } else {
    interval = Math.floor(seconds / 2592000);
    if (interval >= 1) {
      intervalType = 'month';
    } else {
      interval = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
      if (interval >= 1) {
        intervalType = 'day';
      } else {
        interval = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
        if (interval >= 1) {
          intervalType = "hour";
        } else {
          interval = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
          if (interval >= 1) {
            intervalType = "minute";
          } else {
            interval = seconds;
            intervalType = "second";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (interval > 1 || interval === 0) {
    intervalType += 's';
  }

  return interval + ' ' + intervalType;
};
var aDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
console.log(timeSince(new Date(Date.now() - aDay)));
console.log(timeSince(new Date(Date.now() - aDay * 2)));
```

Comment: This doesn't work for seconds as interval is left as 0 from `interval = Math.floor(seconds / 60);`. I added `interval = seconds;` into the final `else` and it works fine.

Comment: If interval is 0, you should also add the "s".

Comment: This is awesome. For TS I had to add a unary operator on `let seconds = Math.floor((+new Date() - date) / 1000);`

Comment: Why do you check even for `interval === 0` in the last `if`?

Comment: @smartmouse so that it will say "0 seconds" instead of "0 second"

Comment: amazing! that is solid

Comment: I made a small modification to allow this to work with times in the future. This goes directly below the "var seconds" line. `var tense = (seconds >= 0) ? 'ago' : 'from now'; seconds = Math.abs(seconds);`

then at the bottom:

    if (Math.abs(interval) > 1 || interval === 0) {
        intervalType += 's';
    }

    return interval + ' ' + intervalType + ' ' + tense;

Answer (score 25):

So here is my version, it works both with dates in the past and in the future.
It uses the [Intl.RelativeTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/RelativeTimeFormat) to provide localized strings, instead of hardcoded strings.
You can pass dates as timestamps, Date objects or parseable date strings.

```js
/**
 * Human readable elapsed or remaining time (example: 3 minutes ago)
 * @param  {Date|Number|String} date A Date object, timestamp or string parsable with Date.parse()
 * @param  {Date|Number|String} [nowDate] A Date object, timestamp or string parsable with Date.parse()
 * @param  {Intl.RelativeTimeFormat} [trf] A Intl formater
 * @return {string} Human readable elapsed or remaining time
 * @author github.com/victornpb
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67338038/938822
 */
function fromNow(date, nowDate = Date.now(), rft = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat(undefined, { numeric: "auto" })) {
    const SECOND = 1000;
    const MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
    const HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
    const DAY = 24 * HOUR;
    const WEEK = 7 * DAY;
    const YEAR = 365 * DAY;
    const MONTH = YEAR / 12;
    const intervals = [
        { ge: YEAR, divisor: YEAR, unit: 'year' },
        { ge: MONTH, divisor: MONTH, unit: 'month' },
        { ge: WEEK, divisor: WEEK, unit: 'week' },
        { ge: DAY, divisor: DAY, unit: 'day' },
        { ge: HOUR, divisor: HOUR, unit: 'hour' },
        { ge: MINUTE, divisor: MINUTE, unit: 'minute' },
        { ge: 30 * SECOND, divisor: SECOND, unit: 'seconds' },
        { ge: 0, divisor: 1, text: 'just now' },
    ];
    const now = typeof nowDate === 'object' ? nowDate.getTime() : new Date(nowDate).getTime();
    const diff = now - (typeof date === 'object' ? date : new Date(date)).getTime();
    const diffAbs = Math.abs(diff);
    for (const interval of intervals) {
        if (diffAbs >= interval.ge) {
            const x = Math.round(Math.abs(diff) / interval.divisor);
            const isFuture = diff < 0;
            return interval.unit ? rft.format(isFuture ? x : -x, interval.unit) : interval.text;
        }
    }
}
```

```js
// examples
fromNow('2020-01-01') // 9 months ago
fromNow(161651684156) // 4 days ago
fromNow(new Date()-1) // just now
fromNow(30000 + Date.now()) // in 30 seconds
fromNow(Date.now() + (1000*60*60*24)) // in 1 day
fromNow(new Date('2029-12-01Z00:00:00.000')) // in 9 years
```

---

Alternative that doesn't use Intl.RelativeTimeFormat

```js
/**
 * Human readable elapsed or remaining time (example: 3 minutes ago)
 * @param  {Date|Number|String} date A Date object, timestamp or string parsable with Date.parse()
 * @return {string} Human readable elapsed or remaining time
 * @author github.com/victornpb
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67338038/938822
 */
function fromNow(date) {
    const SECOND = 1000;
    const MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
    const HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
    const DAY = 24 * HOUR;
    const WEEK = 7 * DAY;
    const YEAR = 365 * DAY;
    const MONTH = YEAR / 12;
    const units = [
        { max: 30 * SECOND, divisor: 1, past1: 'just now', pastN: 'just now', future1: 'just now', futureN: 'just now' },
        { max: MINUTE, divisor: SECOND, past1: 'a second ago', pastN: '# seconds ago', future1: 'in a second', futureN: 'in # seconds' },
        { max: HOUR, divisor: MINUTE, past1: 'a minute ago', pastN: '# minutes ago', future1: 'in a minute', futureN: 'in # minutes' },
        { max: DAY, divisor: HOUR, past1: 'an hour ago', pastN: '# hours ago', future1: 'in an hour', futureN: 'in # hours' },
        { max: WEEK, divisor: DAY, past1: 'yesterday', pastN: '# days ago', future1: 'tomorrow', futureN: 'in # days' },
        { max: 4 * WEEK, divisor: WEEK, past1: 'last week', pastN: '# weeks ago', future1: 'in a week', futureN: 'in # weeks' },
        { max: YEAR, divisor: MONTH, past1: 'last month', pastN: '# months ago', future1: 'in a month', futureN: 'in # months' },
        { max: 100 * YEAR, divisor: YEAR, past1: 'last year', pastN: '# years ago', future1: 'in a year', futureN: 'in # years' },
        { max: 1000 * YEAR, divisor: 100 * YEAR, past1: 'last century', pastN: '# centuries ago', future1: 'in a century', futureN: 'in # centuries' },
        { max: Infinity, divisor: 1000 * YEAR, past1: 'last millennium', pastN: '# millennia ago', future1: 'in a millennium', futureN: 'in # millennia' },
    ];
    const diff = Date.now() - (typeof date === 'object' ? date : new Date(date)).getTime();
    const diffAbs = Math.abs(diff);
    for (const unit of units) {
        if (diffAbs < unit.max) {
            const isFuture = diff < 0;
            const x = Math.round(Math.abs(diff) / unit.divisor);
            if (x <= 1) return isFuture ? unit.future1 : unit.past1;
            return (isFuture ? unit.futureN : unit.pastN).replace('#', x);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Your version has a couple of validation errors. Try it in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play to validate it.

Comment: I just thought after putting so much work in it you would like to make it pass ESLint ;)

Answer (score 20):

A shorter version as used by [Lokely](https://lokely.co):

```
const intervals = [
  { label: 'year', seconds: 31536000 },
  { label: 'month', seconds: 2592000 },
  { label: 'day', seconds: 86400 },
  { label: 'hour', seconds: 3600 },
  { label: 'minute', seconds: 60 },
  { label: 'second', seconds: 1 }
];

function timeSince(date) {
  const seconds = Math.floor((Date.now() - date.getTime()) / 1000);
  const interval = intervals.find(i => i.seconds < seconds);
  const count = Math.floor(seconds / interval.seconds);
  return `${count} ${interval.label}${count !== 1 ? 's' : ''} ago`;
}
```

Comment: The shortest interval has a duration of zero seconds - this results in a division by zero error.

Comment: @apk is right. <60 seconds it prints `Infinity seconds ago`

Comment: doesnt' handle future dates.

Answer (score 15):

You might want to look at humanized_time_span: https://github.com/layam/js_humanized_time_span

It's framework agnostic and fully customizable.

Just download / include the script and then you can do this:

```
humanized_time_span("2011-05-11 12:00:00")  
   => '3 hours ago'

humanized_time_span("2011-05-11 12:00:00", "2011-05-11 16:00:00)  
   => '4 hours ago'
```

or even this:

```
var custom_date_formats = {
  past: [
    { ceiling: 60, text: "less than a minute ago" },
    { ceiling: 86400, text: "$hours hours, $minutes minutes and $seconds seconds ago" },
    { ceiling: null, text: "$years years ago" }
  ],
  future: [
    { ceiling: 60, text: "in less than a minute" },
    { ceiling: 86400, text: "in $hours hours, $minutes minutes and $seconds seconds time" },
    { ceiling: null, text: "in $years years" }
  ]
}

humanized_time_span("2010/09/10 10:00:00", "2010/09/10 10:00:05", custom_date_formats) 
  => "less than a minute ago"
```

Read the docs for more info.

Comment: Just means that it doesn't rely on jQuery or even having a DOM.

Comment: It gives me `NaN years ago` why??

Comment: darn it I got it... your example of its use is wrong. you actually delimit first numbers with slash rather than "-".. like this `humanized_time_span("2011/05/11 12:00:00")`

Comment: it might depend on your local culture and differ between users :)

Answer (score 15):

Changed the function above to

```
function timeSince(date) {

    var seconds = Math.floor(((new Date().getTime()/1000) - date)),
    interval = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);

    if (interval > 1) return interval + "y";

    interval = Math.floor(seconds / 2592000);
    if (interval > 1) return interval + "m";

    interval = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
    if (interval >= 1) return interval + "d";

    interval = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    if (interval >= 1) return interval + "h";

    interval = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    if (interval > 1) return interval + "m ";

    return Math.floor(seconds) + "s";
}
```

Otherwise it would show things like "75 minutes" (between 1 and 2 hours). It also now assumes input date is a Unix timestamp.

Comment: Divide date by 1000 please.

Comment: I used this where data came from a database with Unix timestamps in seconds. When it is in milliseconds you do need to divide by 1000.

Answer (score 15):

An ES6 version of the code provided by @user1012181:

```js
const epochs = [
    ['year', 31536000],
    ['month', 2592000],
    ['day', 86400],
    ['hour', 3600],
    ['minute', 60],
    ['second', 1]
];

const getDuration = (timeAgoInSeconds) => {
    for (let [name, seconds] of epochs) {
        const interval = Math.floor(timeAgoInSeconds / seconds);
        if (interval >= 1) {
            return {
                interval: interval,
                epoch: name
            };
        }
    }
};

const timeAgo = (date) => {
    const timeAgoInSeconds = Math.floor((new Date() - new Date(date)) / 1000);
    const {interval, epoch} = getDuration(timeAgoInSeconds);
    const suffix = interval === 1 ? '' : 's';
    return `${interval} ${epoch}${suffix} ago`;
};
```

Edited with @ibe-vanmeenen suggestions. (Thanks!)

Comment: You should also include "second: 1" in EPOCHS, otherwise it will break if it's less than 1 minute ago :). The last 3 vars could also be a constant no?

Comment: Also, EPOCHS should be an array, as objects do not guarantee properties order. I've stored my changes in https://gist.github.com/IbeVanmeenen/4e3e58820c9168806e57530563612886. You're welcome to copy them to edit this answer :)

Comment: It will also break if you use current date/time e.g. Date.now() since the interval will result to undefined. I recommend to add support for "just now".

Answer (score 11):

Much readable and cross browser compatible code:

As given by @Travis

```js
var DURATION_IN_SECONDS = {
  epochs: ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute'],
  year: 31536000,
  month: 2592000,
  day: 86400,
  hour: 3600,
  minute: 60
};

function getDuration(seconds) {
  var epoch, interval;

  for (var i = 0; i < DURATION_IN_SECONDS.epochs.length; i++) {
    epoch = DURATION_IN_SECONDS.epochs[i];
    interval = Math.floor(seconds / DURATION_IN_SECONDS[epoch]);
    if (interval >= 1) {
      return {
        interval: interval,
        epoch: epoch
      };
    }
  }

};

function timeSince(date) {
  var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - new Date(date)) / 1000);
  var duration = getDuration(seconds);
  var suffix = (duration.interval > 1 || duration.interval === 0) ? 's' : '';
  return duration.interval + ' ' + duration.epoch + suffix;
};

alert(timeSince('2015-09-17T18:53:23'));
```

Comment: Note that this makes some wrongful assumptions, such as every day being 86,400 seconds (unless time zone is set to UTC, this isn't always true thanks to UTC)

Answer (score 9):

Simple and readable version:

```js
const relativeTimePeriods = [
    [31536000, 'year'],
    [2419200, 'month'],
    [604800, 'week'],
    [86400, 'day'],
    [3600, 'hour'],
    [60, 'minute'],
    [1, 'second']
];

function relativeTime(date, isUtc=true) {
    if (!(date instanceof Date)) date = new Date(date * 1000);
    const seconds = (new Date() - date) / 1000;
    for (let [secondsPer, name] of relativeTimePeriods) {
        if (seconds >= secondsPer) {
            const amount = Math.floor(seconds / secondsPer);
            return `${amount} ${name}${amount ? 's' : ''}s ago`;
        }
    }
    return 'Just now';
}
```

Comment: This works well but there is a logical error I had to correct.

I changed this             return `${amount} ${name}${amount ? 's' : ''}s ago`; 
to             return `${amount} ${name}${amount >1 ? 's' : ''} ago`;

to avoid returning two 's' in front of plural names and displaying the singular without any 's'

Answer (score 8):

from now, unix timestamp param,

```
function timeSince(ts){
    now = new Date();
    ts = new Date(ts*1000);
    var delta = now.getTime() - ts.getTime();

    delta = delta/1000; //us to s

    var ps, pm, ph, pd, min, hou, sec, days;

    if(delta<=59){
        ps = (delta>1) ? "s": "";
        return delta+" second"+ps
    }

    if(delta>=60 && delta<=3599){
        min = Math.floor(delta/60);
        sec = delta-(min*60);
        pm = (min>1) ? "s": "";
        ps = (sec>1) ? "s": "";
        return min+" minute"+pm+" "+sec+" second"+ps;
    }

    if(delta>=3600 && delta<=86399){
        hou = Math.floor(delta/3600);
        min = Math.floor((delta-(hou*3600))/60);
        ph = (hou>1) ? "s": "";
        pm = (min>1) ? "s": "";
        return hou+" hour"+ph+" "+min+" minute"+pm;
    } 

    if(delta>=86400){
        days = Math.floor(delta/86400);
        hou =  Math.floor((delta-(days*86400))/60/60);
        pd = (days>1) ? "s": "";
        ph = (hou>1) ? "s": "";
        return days+" day"+pd+" "+hou+" hour"+ph;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

This should properly handle any valid timestamp, including Date.now(), singular units, and future dates. I left out months, but those should be easy to add in. I tried to keep it readable as possible.

```js
function getTimeInterval(date) {
  let seconds = Math.floor((Date.now() - date) / 1000);
  let unit = "second";
  let direction = "ago";
  if (seconds < 0) {
    seconds = -seconds;
    direction = "from now";
  }
  let value = seconds;
  if (seconds >= 31536000) {
    value = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
    unit = "year";
  } else if (seconds >= 86400) {
    value = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
    unit = "day";
  } else if (seconds >= 3600) {
    value = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    unit = "hour";
  } else if (seconds >= 60) {
    value = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    unit = "minute";
  }
  if (value != 1)
    unit = unit + "s";
  return value + " " + unit + " " + direction;
}

console.log(getTimeInterval(Date.now())); // 0 seconds ago
console.log(getTimeInterval(Date.now() + 1000)); // 1 second from now
console.log(getTimeInterval(Date.now() - 1000)); // 1 second ago
console.log(getTimeInterval(Date.now() + 60000)); // 1 minute from now
console.log(getTimeInterval(Date.now() - 120000)); // 2 minutes ago
console.log(getTimeInterval(Date.now() + 120000)); // 2 minutes from now
console.log(getTimeInterval(Date.now() + 3600000)); // 1 hour from now
console.log(getTimeInterval(Date.now() + 360000000000)); // 11 years from now
console.log(getTimeInterval(0)); // 49 years ago
```

Answer (score 6):

Although the question was asked quite long time ago, writing this answer with hope it will help somebody.

Pass the date you want to start to count from. Using `moment().fromNow()` of **momentjs**: (See more information [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/))

```
getRelativeTime(date) {
    const d = new Date(date * 1000);
    return moment(d).fromNow();
}
```

If you want to change information provided for dates fromNow you write your custom relative time for moment.

For example, in my own case I wanted to print `'one month ago'` instead of `'a month ago'` (*provided by moment(d).fromNow()*). In this case, you can write something given below.

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    relativeTime: {
        future: 'in %s',
        past: '%s ago',
        s: 'a few seconds',
        ss: '%d seconds',
        m: '1 m',
        mm: '%d minutes',
        h: '1 h',
        hh: '%d hours',
        d: '1 d',
        dd: '%d days',
        M: '1 month',
        MM: '%d months',
        y: '1 y',
        yy: '%d years'
    }
});
```

**NOTE**: I wrote my code for project in **Angular 6**

Comment: @Nima, delighted if it was helpful :))

Answer (score 6):

Can also use the dayjs [relativeTime](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/dev/docs/en/Plugin.md#relativetime) plugin to solve this.

```
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';
import * as relativeTime from 'dayjs/plugin/relativeTime';

dayjs.extend(relativeTime);
dayjs(dayjs('1990')).fromNow(); // x years ago
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function dateToHowManyAgo(stringDate){
    var currDate = new Date();
    var diffMs=currDate.getTime() - new Date(stringDate).getTime();
    var sec=diffMs/1000;
    if(sec<60)
        return parseInt(sec)+' second'+(parseInt(sec)>1?'s':'')+' ago';
    var min=sec/60;
    if(min<60)
        return parseInt(min)+' minute'+(parseInt(min)>1?'s':'')+' ago';
    var h=min/60;
    if(h<24)
        return parseInt(h)+' hour'+(parseInt(h)>1?'s':'')+' ago';
    var d=h/24;
    if(d<30)
        return parseInt(d)+' day'+(parseInt(d)>1?'s':'')+' ago';
    var m=d/30;
    if(m<12)
        return parseInt(m)+' month'+(parseInt(m)>1?'s':'')+' ago';
    var y=m/12;
    return parseInt(y)+' year'+(parseInt(y)>1?'s':'')+' ago';
}
console.log(dateToHowManyAgo('2019-11-07 19:17:06'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of these answers fail to account for plurals (eg. "1 minutes ago" when we want "1 minute ago")

```
const MINUTE = 60;
const HOUR = MINUTE * 60;
const DAY = HOUR * 24;
const WEEK = DAY * 7;
const MONTH = DAY * 30;
const YEAR = DAY * 365;

function getTimeAgo(date) {
  const secondsAgo = Math.round((Date.now() - Number(date)) / 1000);

  if (secondsAgo < MINUTE) {
    return secondsAgo + ` second${secondsAgo !== 1 ? "s" : ""} ago`;
  }

  let divisor;
  let unit = "";

  if (secondsAgo < HOUR) {
    [divisor, unit] = [MINUTE, "minute"];
  } else if (secondsAgo < DAY) {
    [divisor, unit] = [HOUR, "hour"];
  } else if (secondsAgo < WEEK) {
    [divisor, unit] = [DAY, "day"];
  } else if (secondsAgo < MONTH) {
    [divisor, unit] = [WEEK, "week"];
  } else if (secondsAgo < YEAR) {
    [divisor, unit] = [MONTH, "month"];
  } else {
    [divisor, unit] = [YEAR, "year"];
  }

  const count = Math.floor(secondsAgo / divisor);
  return `${count} ${unit}${count > 1 ? "s" : ""} ago`;
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(getTimeAgo(date));
// 1 second ago
// 2 seconds ago
// 1 minute ago
// 2 minutes ago
// ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I used an old answer by Possible 11 and I added **Intl.RelativeTimeFormat** for translations.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73331658/673809

```js
function timeAgo (value) {
    const seconds = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - new Date(value).getTime()) / 1000)
    let interval = seconds / 31536000
    const rtf = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat("en", { numeric: 'auto' })
    if (interval > 1) { return rtf.format(-Math.floor(interval), 'year') }
    interval = seconds / 2592000
    if (interval > 1) { return rtf.format(-Math.floor(interval), 'month') }
    interval = seconds / 86400
    if (interval > 1) { return rtf.format(-Math.floor(interval), 'day') }
    interval = seconds / 3600
    if (interval > 1) { return rtf.format(-Math.floor(interval), 'hour') }
    interval = seconds / 60
    if (interval > 1) { return rtf.format(-Math.floor(interval), 'minute') }
    return rtf.format(-Math.floor(interval), 'second')
}

console.log(timeAgo('2022-08-12 20:50:20'))
```

Answer (score 3):

I write one with js and python, used in two projects, very nice and simple: [a simple library (less then 2kb) used to format date with `*** time ago` statement.](https://github.com/hustcc/timeago.js)

simple, small, easy used, and well tested.

1. `npm install timeago.js`
2. `import timeago from 'timeago.js'; // or use script tag`
3. use api `format`.

Sample:

```
var timeagoIns  = timeago();
timeagoIns .format('2016-06-12');
```

Also you can render in real-time.

```
var timeagoIns = timeago();
timeagoIns.render(document.querySelectorAll('time'));
```

Comment: As of 4.0 you can use a destructured import instead:
`import { format, render, cancel, register } from 'timeago.js';`

Answer (score 3):

Replying to @Stas Parshin answer, it is best answer here with less code, but it has bug when using with typescript, the .format function of Intl takes 2 inputs

1. number,
2. Units - i.e of type 'RelativeTimeFormatUnit' so if you pass a object key typescript will through error saying unit must be of type RelativeTimeFormatUnit and not of type string, so the work-around for this is to use the type to make another list of same type and rest you can have look at code...
   Happy coding.

   ```
   function timeAgo(input) {
    const date = (input instanceof Date) ? input : new Date(input);
    const formatter = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('en');
    const ranges = [
      ['years', 3600 * 24 * 365],
      ['months', 3600 * 24 * 30],
      ['weeks', 3600 * 24 * 7],
      ['days', 3600 * 24],
      ['hours', 3600],
      ['minutes', 60],
      ['seconds', 1],
    ] as const;
    const secondsElapsed = (date.getTime() - Date.now()) / 1000;

    for (const [rangeType, rangeVal] of ranges) {
      if (rangeVal < Math.abs(secondsElapsed)) {
        const delta = secondsElapsed / rangeVal;
        return formatter.format(Math.round(delta), rangeType);
      }
    }}

    console.log(timeAgo('2021-08-09T15:29:01+0000'));
   ```

Comment: Nice! Let me link your answer in the original one so people are aware of this

Comment: Instead of this craziness, just use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69122877/6511519, but after `key` write `as keyof typeof ranges` ... The "workaround" above is just a pointless waste of space and time...

Answer (score 2):

I have modified Sky Sanders' version. The Math.floor(...) operations are evaluated in the if block

```
       var timeSince = function(date) {
            var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);
            var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
            if (seconds < 5){
                return "just now";
            }else if (seconds < 60){
                return seconds + " seconds ago";
            }
            else if (seconds < 3600) {
                minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60)
                if(minutes > 1)
                    return minutes + " minutes ago";
                else
                    return "1 minute ago";
            }
            else if (seconds < 86400) {
                hours = Math.floor(seconds/3600)
                if(hours > 1)
                    return hours + " hours ago";
                else
                    return "1 hour ago";
            }
            //2 days and no more
            else if (seconds < 172800) {
                days = Math.floor(seconds/86400)
                if(days > 1)
                    return days + " days ago";
                else
                    return "1 day ago";
            }
            else{

                //return new Date(time).toLocaleDateString();
                return date.getDate().toString() + " " + months[date.getMonth()] + ", " + date.getFullYear();
            }
        }
```

Comment: there is a typo in the last else if `return days + "1 day ago";` should be `return "1 day ago";`

Answer (score 2):

```
function timeago(date) {
    var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);
    if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*365.25)) >= 2) return Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*365.25)) + " years ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*365.25)) >= 1) return "1 year ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*30.4)) >= 2) return Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*30.4)) + " months ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*30.4)) >= 1) return "1 month ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*7)) >= 2) return Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*7)) + " weeks ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24*7)) >= 1) return "1 week ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24)) >= 2) return Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24)) + " days ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60*24)) >= 1) return "1 day ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60)) >= 2) return Math.round(seconds/(60*60)) + " hours ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/(60*60)) >= 1) return "1 hour ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/60) >= 2) return Math.round(seconds/60) + " minutes ago";
    else if(Math.round(seconds/60) >= 1) return "1 minute ago";
    else if(seconds >= 2)return seconds + " seconds ago";
    else return seconds + "1 second ago";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My stab at this based on other answers.

```
function timeSince(date) {
    let minute = 60;
    let hour   = minute * 60;
    let day    = hour   * 24;
    let month  = day    * 30;
    let year   = day    * 365;

    let suffix = ' ago';

    let elapsed = Math.floor((Date.now() - date) / 1000);

    if (elapsed < minute) {
        return 'just now';
    }

    // get an array in the form of [number, string]
    let a = elapsed < hour  && [Math.floor(elapsed / minute), 'minute'] ||
            elapsed < day   && [Math.floor(elapsed / hour), 'hour']     ||
            elapsed < month && [Math.floor(elapsed / day), 'day']       ||
            elapsed < year  && [Math.floor(elapsed / month), 'month']   ||
            [Math.floor(elapsed / year), 'year'];

    // pluralise and append suffix
    return a[0] + ' ' + a[1] + (a[0] === 1 ? '' : 's') + suffix;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering 10 years old question to help the newcomers.

We can use this package for that [javascript-time-ago](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-time-ago)

```
 
// Load locale-specific relative date/time formatting rules.
import en from 'javascript-time-ago/locale/en'
 
// Add locale-specific relative date/time formatting rules.
TimeAgo.addLocale(en)
 
// Create relative date/time formatter.
const timeAgo = new TimeAgo('en-US')
 
timeAgo.format(new Date())
// "just now"
 
timeAgo.format(Date.now() - 60 * 1000)
// "a minute ago"
 
timeAgo.format(Date.now() - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
// "2 hours ago"
 
timeAgo.format(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
// "a day ago"
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const createdAt = moment(created_at).fromNow()
```

and a customized solution

```js
        const duration = moment.duration(moment().diff(moment(created_at)))
        const createdAt = duration.as('week') >= 1
          ? `${Math.floor(duration.as('week'))} week(s)`
          : duration.as('day') >= 1
            ? `${Math.floor(duration.as('day'))} day(s)`
            : duration.as('hour') >= 1
              ? `${Math.floor(duration.as('hour'))} hour(s)`
              : `${Math.floor(duration.as('minute'))} minute(s)`
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution..

```
(function(global){
            const SECOND   = 1;
            const MINUTE   = 60;
            const HOUR     = 3600;
            const DAY      = 86400;
            const MONTH    = 2629746;
            const YEAR     = 31556952;
            const DECADE   = 315569520;

            global.timeAgo = function(date){
                var now = new Date();
                var diff = Math.round(( now - date ) / 1000);

                var unit = '';
                var num = 0;
                var plural = false;

                switch(true){
                    case diff <= 0:
                        return 'just now';
                    break;

                    case diff < MINUTE:
                        num = Math.round(diff / SECOND);
                        unit = 'sec';
                        plural = num > 1;
                    break;

                    case diff < HOUR:
                        num = Math.round(diff / MINUTE);
                        unit = 'min';
                        plural = num > 1;
                    break;

                    case diff < DAY:
                        num = Math.round(diff / HOUR);
                        unit = 'hour';
                        plural = num > 1;
                    break;

                    case diff < MONTH:
                        num = Math.round(diff / DAY);
                        unit = 'day';
                        plural = num > 1;
                    break;

                    case diff < YEAR:
                        num = Math.round(diff / MONTH);
                        unit = 'month';
                        plural = num > 1;
                    break;

                    case diff < DECADE:
                        num = Math.round(diff / YEAR);
                        unit = 'year';
                        plural = num > 1;
                    break;

                    default:
                        num = Math.round(diff / YEAR);
                        unit = 'year';
                        plural = num > 1;
                }

                var str = '';
                if(num){
                    str += `${num} `;
                }

                str += `${unit}`;

                if(plural){
                    str += 's';
                }

                str += ' ago';

                return str;
            }
        })(window);

        console.log(timeAgo(new Date()));
        console.log(timeAgo(new Date('Jun 03 2018 15:12:19 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)')));
        console.log(timeAgo(new Date('Jun 03 2018 13:12:19 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)')));
        console.log(timeAgo(new Date('May 28 2018 13:12:19 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)')));
        console.log(timeAgo(new Date('May 28 2017 13:12:19 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)')));
        console.log(timeAgo(new Date('May 28 2000 13:12:19 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)')));
        console.log(timeAgo(new Date('Sep 10 1994 13:12:19 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)')));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 I achieve this by following method

   timeAgo = (date) => {
            var ms = (new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime();
            var seconds = Math.floor(ms / 1000);
            var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
        var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
        var months = Math.floor(days / 30);
        var years = Math.floor(months / 12);
    
        if (ms === 0) {
            return 'Just now';
        } if (seconds < 60) {
            return seconds + ' seconds Ago';
        } if (minutes < 60) {
            return minutes + ' minutes Ago';
        } if (hours < 24) {
            return hours + ' hours Ago';
        } if (days < 30) {
            return days + ' days Ago';
        } if (months < 12) {
            return months + ' months Ago';
        } else {
            return years + ' years Ago';
        }
    
    }
    
        console.log(timeAgo(new Date()));
        console.log(timeAgo(new Date('Jun 27 2020 10:12:19')));
        console.log(timeAgo(new Date('Jun 27 2020 00:12:19')));
        console.log(timeAgo(new Date('May 28 2020 13:12:19')));
        console.log(timeAgo(new Date('May 28 2017 13:12:19')));
```

Comment: How does this improve upon any of the existing answers, including Sky Sanders' from _ten years ago_?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit simplified version of @sky-sanders answer.

```
function timeSince(date) {

  var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);
  var divisors = [31536000, 2592000, 86400, 3600, 60, 1]
  var description = ["years", "months", "days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds"]
  var result = [];

  var interval = seconds;

  for (i = 0; i < divisors.length; i++) {
    interval = Math.floor(seconds / divisors[i])
    if (interval > 1) {
      result.push(interval + " " + description[i])
    }
    seconds -= interval * divisors[i]
  }

  return result.join(" ")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using date-fns, you can use the built-in [`formatDistance`](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.1/docs/formatDistance) (previously [`distanceInWords`](https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/distanceInWords)):

```
const date1 = new Date(2014, 6, 2);
const date2 = new Date(2015, 0, 1);
const options = { addSuffix: true }
const result = formatDistance(date1, date2, options);
//=> '6 months ago'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this and almost implemented one of these solutions, but a colleague reminded me to check the `react-intl` library  since we were already using it.

So adding to the solutions...in the case you are using the `react-intl` library, they have a `<FormattedRelative>` component for this.

https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Components#formattedrelative

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did (the object returns the unit of time along with its value):

```js
function timeSince(post_date, reference)
{
 var reference = reference ? new Date(reference) : new Date(),
  diff = reference - new Date(post_date + ' GMT-0000'),
  date = new Date(diff),
  object = { unit: null, value: null };
 
 if (diff < 86400000)
 {
  var secs  = date.getSeconds(),
   mins  = date.getMinutes(),
   hours = date.getHours(),
   array = [ ['second', secs], ['minute', mins], ['hour', hours] ];
 }
 else
 {
  var days   = date.getDate(),
   weeks  = Math.floor(days / 7),
   months = date.getMonth(),
   years  = date.getFullYear() - 1970,
   array  = [ ['day', days], ['week', weeks], ['month', months], ['year', years] ];
 }

 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
 {
  array[i][0] += array[i][1] != 1 ? 's' : '';

  object.unit  = array[i][1] >= 1 ? array[i][0] : object.unit;
  object.value = array[i][1] >= 1 ? array[i][1] : object.value;
 }

 return object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function calDateAgo(dString=null){
    //var dString = "2021-04-1 12:00:00";
     
    var d1 = new Date(dString);
    var d2 = new Date();
    var t2 = d2.getTime();
    var t1 = d1.getTime();
    var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
    var d2Y = d2.getFullYear();
    var d1M = d1.getMonth();
    var d2M = d2.getMonth();
     
    var time_obj = {};
    time_obj.year = d2.getFullYear()-d1.getFullYear();
    time_obj.month = (d2M+12*d2Y)-(d1M+12*d1Y);
    time_obj.week = parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000*7));
    time_obj.day = parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000));
    time_obj.hour = parseInt((t2-t1)/(3600*1000));
    time_obj.minute = parseInt((t2-t1)/(60*1000));
    time_obj.second = parseInt((t2-t1)/(1000));

    for (const obj_key in time_obj) {
        if(time_obj[obj_key] == 0){
            delete time_obj[obj_key];
        }
    }
    var ago_text = 'just now';

    if(typeof Object.keys(time_obj)[0] != 'undefined'){
        var time_key = Object.keys(time_obj)[0];
        var time_val = time_obj[Object.keys(time_obj)[0]];
        time_key += (time_val > 1) ? 's':'';
        ago_text = time_val+' '+time_key+' ago'; 
    }
    
    return ago_text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mdiv(dividend, divisor) {
    return [ Math.floor(dividend/divisor), dividend % divisor ];
}
// pass in milliseconds, gained by Date1.getTime() - Date2.getTime()
// if max_units is two, the result will be, for example
// 2years 12months ago, or 2hours 38minutes ago
// return formated period

function readable_period(ms, max_units=2){
    let [yy, yr] = mdiv(ms, 3.154e10);
    let [mm, mr] = mdiv(yr, 2.628e9);
    let [dd, dr] = mdiv(mr, 8.64e7);
    let [hh, hr] = mdiv(dr, 3.6e6);
    let [tt, ss] = mdiv(hr, 6e4);

    var ymdht = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute'];
    let res = [];
    [yy, mm, dd, hh, tt].forEach((tis, ii)=>{
        if(res.length === max_units){return};
        if(tis !== 0){
            res.push(tis === 1 ? `${tis}${ymdht[ii]}` : `${tis}${ymdht[ii]}s`);
        }
    });
    return res.length === 0 ? '' : res.join(' ') + ' ago';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon):

```
DateTime.toRelative()
```

https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetorelative

Here are some more examples:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

// toRelative
console.log(DateTime.now().minus({ seconds: 1 }).toRelative()) // 1 second ago
console.log(DateTime.now().minus({ seconds: 10 }).toRelative()) // 10 seconds ago
console.log(DateTime.now().minus({ days: 2 }).toRelative())
console.log(DateTime.now().minus({ years: 3 }).toRelative())
console.log(DateTime.now().plus({ years: 3 }).toRelative())
console.log(DateTime.now().plus({ days: 2 }).toRelative())
console.log(DateTime.now().plus({ seconds: 1 }).toRelative())
console.log(DateTime.now().plus({ seconds: 10 }).toRelative())

// toRelativeCalendar
console.log(DateTime.now().minus({ seconds: 1 }).toRelativeCalendar()) // today
console.log(DateTime.now().minus({ seconds: 10 }).toRelativeCalendar()) // today
console.log(DateTime.now().minus({ days: 2 }).toRelativeCalendar())
console.log(DateTime.now().minus({ years: 3 }).toRelativeCalendar())
console.log(DateTime.now().plus({ years: 3 }).toRelativeCalendar())
console.log(DateTime.now().plus({ days: 2 }).toRelativeCalendar())
console.log(DateTime.now().plus({ seconds: 1 }).toRelativeCalendar())
console.log(DateTime.now().plus({ seconds: 10 }).toRelativeCalendar())
```

```html
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this package: [javascript-time-ago](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-time-ago)

- set `TimeAgo`

  ```
   import TimeAgo from 'javascript-time-ago'
   import en from 'javascript-time-ago/locale/en.json'

   TimeAgo.addDefaultLocale(en)
  ```
- write a function
  // twitter-now is twitter style. check docs for more options

  ```
  const clockToDateString = (timestamp) =>
    timeAgo.format(new Date(timestamp.toNumber() * 1000), 'twitter-now')
  ```
- use it in dom

  ```
     <div >
        {clockToDateString(post.postTime)}
      </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

to use this, just LITERALLY COPY ALL of this code & just import it in your component or where ever & just place in your ISOstring() date inside: `showTimeAgo("2022-06-20T13:42:29-05:00")` & you will get automatic time updates for every scenario.

*sidenote*: I made an npm package for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/showtimeago

```
export const showTimeAgo = () => {
    const MONTH_NAMES = [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December',
    ];

    function getOrdinalNum() {
        return (
            n +
            (n > 0
                ? ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][
                      (n > 3 && n < 21) || n % 10 > 3 ? 0 : n % 10
                  ]
                : '')
        );
    }

    function getFormattedDate(
        date,
        preformattedDate = false,
        hideYear = false
    ) {
        const day = date.getDate();
        const month = MONTH_NAMES[date.getMonth()];
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        let hours = date.getHours();
        let minutes = date.getMinutes();

        let ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';

        switch(true){
            case (hours > 12):
                hours = hours - 12;
                break;
            case (hours === 0):
                hours = 12;
                break;
            case(minutes < 10):
                minutes = `0${minutes}`;
                break;
            case(preformattedDate):
            // Today at 10:20am
            // Yesterday at 10:20am
                return `${preformattedDate} at ${hours}:${minutes} ${ampm}`;

            case(hideYear):
                // January 10th at 10:20pm
                return `${month} ${getOrdinalNum(
                    day
                )}, at ${hours}:${minutes} ${ampm}`;
            default:
                // January 10th 2022 at 10:20pm
                return `${month} ${getOrdinalNum(
                    day
                )}, ${year} at ${hours}:${minutes} ${ampm}`;
        }
        
    }

    // --- Main function
    function timeAgo(dateParam) {
        if (!dateParam) {
            return null;
        }

        const date =
            typeof dateParam === 'object' ? dateParam : new Date(dateParam);
        const DAY_IN_MS = 86400000; // 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        const today = new Date();

        const yesterday = new Date(today - DAY_IN_MS);

        const seconds = Math.round((today - date) / 1000);
        const minutes = Math.round(seconds / 60);
        const hour = Math.round(seconds / 3600);
        const day = Math.round(seconds / 86400);
        const month = Math.round(seconds / 2629800);
        const year = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
        const isToday = today.toDateString() === date.toDateString();
        const isYesterday =
            yesterday.toDateString() === date.toDateString();
        const isThisYear = today.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear();

        switch(true){
            case (seconds < 5):
                return 'now';
            case (seconds < 60):
                return `${seconds} seconds ago`;
            case (seconds < 90):
                return 'about a minute ago';
            case (minutes < 60):
                return `${minutes} minutes ago`;
            case (hour === 1 && hour < 2):
                return `${hour} hour ago`; // 1 hour ago
            case (hour > 1 && hour <= 12):
                return `${hour} hours ago`; // 2 hours ago
            case (isToday):
                return getFormattedDate(date, 'Today'); // Today at 10:20am
            case (isYesterday): 
                return getFormattedDate(date, 'Yesterday'); // Yesterday at 10:20am
            case(day > 1 && day <= 30):
                return `${day} days ago`; // 2 days ago
            case (isThisYear):
                return getFormattedDate(date, false, true); // January 10th at 10:20pm 
            case (day > 30 && month <= 1):
                return `${hour} month ago`; // 1 month ago
            case (month > 1 && month <= 12):
                return `${month} months ago`; // 2 months ago
            case (year === 1):
                return `${year} year ago`; // 1 year ago
            case (year > 1):
                return `${year} years ago`; // 2 years ago
            default:
                return getFormattedDate(date); // January 10th 2022 at 10:20pm
        }
    }

    return timeAgo(date);
};

console.log(showTimeAgo("2022-06-20T13:42:29-05:00"));-05:00"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are good for old java scripts. But it's not working well on new EC6 JavaScript or TypeScript. Below is a very short and simple function for the latest JavaScript, TypeScript, AngularJs, ReactJs, and NodeJs to return the time ago as per the given date and time.

```
  public timeAgo(date) {
    var seconds = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - new Date(date).getTime()) / 1000);
    var interval = seconds / 31536000;
    if (interval > 1) return Math.floor(interval) + " years";
    interval = seconds / 2592000;
    if (interval > 1) return Math.floor(interval) + " months";
    interval = seconds / 86400;
    if (interval > 1) return Math.floor(interval) + " days";
    interval = seconds / 3600;
    if (interval > 1) return Math.floor(interval) + " hours";
    interval = seconds / 60;
    if (interval > 1) return Math.floor(interval) + " minutes";
    return Math.floor(seconds) + " seconds";
  }

console.log(timeAgo('2022-08-12 20:50:20'));
// 2 hours ago, as per the given date time string.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const timeHandler = (time: any) => {
      var a = moment(); //now
      var b = moment.utc(time);
      const sec = a.diff(b, 'seconds');
      const minuts = a.diff(b, 'minutes');
      const hours = a.diff(b, 'hours');
      const days = a.diff(b, 'days');
      const weeks = a.diff(b, 'weeks');
      return weeks == 0
        ? days == 0
          ? hours == 0
            ? minuts == 0
              ? sec >= 0 && `${sec}s ago`
              : `${minuts}m ago`
            : `${hours}h ago`
          : `${days}d ago`
        : `${weeks}w ago`;
    };

console.log(timeHandler('2022-11-11T12:11:06.6103808'))
```

Answer (score 0):

dayjs has a neat little one liner. Here is a function I pass a timestamp(ts) as a string. ts is in ISO format already.

```
export function nTimeAgo(ts: string){ 
  return `${dayjs().to(dayjs(ts), true)} ago`;
}
```

Link to docs here: https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/relative-time