# Getting "Time since" using preset time. ("2012-03-27 16:01:48 CEST")

Tags: php, javascript, html, time

I'm trying to convert this "2012-03-27 16:01:48 CEST" into "1 hour and 22 minutes since". Preferably automatic time-zone management.

I can not change how the time is set. It will always be "2012-03-27 16:01:48 CEST" or something similar. Any ideas? 
I'm open for anything!

Comment: This answer might help you.
[How to format time since xxx e.g. “4 minutes ago” similar to Stack Exchange sites][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177836/how-to-format-time-since-xxx-e-g-4-minutes-ago-similar-to-stack-exchange-site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love DateTime!

```
$a = new DateTime('2012-03-27 16:01:48 CEST');
$b = new DateTime();

$diff = $b->diff($a);

echo $diff->h,' hours and ',$diff->i,' minutes';
```

Comment: You need >= PHP 5.3 to get it work, and I am sorry I mistook `m` for minutes, but it is actually `i`. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Comment: Would you look at that! Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://www.datejs.com/ It's a handy library for formatting and calculating dates.

Answer (score 0):

Check php [gmdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) function