# convert pubDate to x mins ago in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert pubDate(eg. "Sat, 14 Feb 2015 19:02:00 +0000") from rss to something like "x mins ago" like on twitter posts.

Is there a function which can convert pubDate format to something like "x mins ago"?

Comment: Check out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177836/how-to-format-time-since-xxx-e-g-4-minutes-ago-similar-to-stack-exchange-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be an overkill in this case, but if the opportunity show [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is just awesome!

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a javascript datetime library, to use it for this, you'd do:

```
moment(yourdate).fromNow()
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Comment: You have more then that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer :

link : https://coderwall.com/p/uub3pw/javascript-timeago-func-e-g-8-hours-ago

there is jQuery plugin also : timeago

Comment: this answer was helpful.