# Format date to only show the least minimum relative time segment i.e 50s, 1m, 2h, 3d etc

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to show the least minimum time segment based on a unix timestamp.

Example:

1. "50 seconds ago" needs to be 50s.
2. "65 seconds ago" needs to be 1m because its more 60 seconds is in minutes.
3. "65 minutes ago" needs to be 1h because its more 60 minutes is in minutes.
4. "25 hours ago" => 1d.
5. "8 days ago" => 1w.
6. ... 1mon (for months).
7. ... 2y (for years).

I have tried a few libraries like [moment](http://momentjs.com/) i.e.

```
moment.unix(1440187622).fromNow()
```

but that returns a "sentence", however its not exactly what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177836/how-to-format-time-since-xxx-e-g-4-minutes-ago-similar-to-stack-exchange-site

Comment: Not everyone likes "friendly" formats. Seeing 4 items with "yesterday" does not help to determine when they occurred relative to each other. :-)

Comment: You can do it yourself with about 12 lines of code. Did you try?

Comment: @RobG Maybe, but in this case that's what I want to show.

Comment: @jcaron I gave it a quick try but I wanted to see some other opinions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a look at moment.js [durations](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)? You could write a function like this:

```
function segment(duration) {
  return duration.years() > 0 ? duration.years() + 'y' :
    duration.months() > 0 ? duration.months() + 'mon' :
    // ...
    duration.seconds() > 0 ? duration.seconds() + 's' : '';
}
segment(moment.duration(moment.diff(moment(),moment.unix(1440187622))))
```