# How do I display time since creation instead of time created

Tags: python, django

I am working on displaying a post in django and currently to display when the post was created, I am using `{{ instance.post_created }}`.

I was wondering if there was anyway I could get it to say `"2 days ago"` if the post was made on the `28th of Jan` and the person was viewing it on the `30th of Jan` as an example.

Comment: [`naturaltime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Naturaltime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime) or do it by hand using [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177836/how-to-format-time-since-xxx-e-g-4-minutes-ago-similar-to-stack-exchange-site)