# Changing Time Format In Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, format

I have the time in following format

Dec 29, 2016 10:57:58 PM

How can I display it as days ago format. Like 20days ago or 30days ago using Javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177836/5192105

Answer (score 1):

You could do this on your own, but I recommend using a popular library like moment.js https://momentjs.com/

```
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 5 years ago
moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 5 years ago
moment().startOf('day').fromNow();        // 19 hours ago
moment().endOf('day').fromNow();          // in 5 hours
moment().startOf('hour').fromNow();       // a minute ago
```

Answer (score 0):

the library [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is what most people use for that.