# Add months in local language to date function

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have this function to print out dates or minutes/hours from tweets. It works fine but dates are in English. How can I change the months into e.g. Spanish? The date format is fixed - it comes from the Twitter API.
It looks like this:

```
var $time = "Fri May 04 20:33:17 +0000 2018";

function relative_time(time_value) {
      // How can I apply these months to the function?
      //var months = Array('Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre');

      var values = time_value.split(" ");
      time_value = values[1] + " " + values[2] + ", " + values[5] + " " + values[3];
      var parsed_date = Date.parse(time_value);
      var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
      var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - parsed_date) / 1000);
      var shortdate = time_value.substr(4, 2) + " " + time_value.substr(0, 3);
      delta = delta + (relative_to.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);

      if (delta < 60) {
        return '1m';
      } else if (delta < 120) {
        return '1m';
      } else if (delta < (60 * 60)) {
        return (parseInt(delta / 60)).toString() + 'm';
      } else if (delta < (120 * 60)) {
        return '1h';
      } else if (delta < (24 * 60 * 60)) {
        return (parseInt(delta / 3600)).toString() + 'h';
      } else if (delta < (48 * 60 * 60)) {
        //return '1 day';
        return shortdate;
      } else {
        return shortdate;
      }
    }
```

Check out [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/w8eczjgg/).

Comment: Using a library like MomentJS will make your life easier.

Comment: Are the date formats fixed? If yes,what is the output date format and input date format?

Comment: If your input format is "Fri May 04 20:33:17 +0000 2018" you can easily create a date object by new Date("Fri May 04 20:33:17 +0000 2018")

Comment: The date format is fixed - it comes from the Twitter API: Like `Fri May 04 20:33:17 +0000 2018` - but how can I change it from printing `May` to `Mayo`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $time = "Fri May 04 20:33:17 +0000 2018";

function relative_time(time_value) {
    var date = new Date(time_value);
    var months= ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 
    'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];
    return date.getDate()+ ' '+ months[date.getMonth()];
   }

relative_time($time);
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Partly, the shortdate and delta part is not working - like `1m`  or `1h` ago.

Comment: write your expected output here

Comment: I'm using this function instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12475270/1583995 - thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date('Fri May 04 20:33:17 +0000 2018');
var months= ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];
var outDate= date.getDate()+ ' '+ months[date.getMonth()];
```

Comment: But how is this going to work with the function and the way it splits the dates, etc.?

Comment: @Meek , please elaborate your query.

Comment: Passing the input in Date() will create a Date object. Then you can have all the date operations over that.

Comment: I really appreciate your time. Can you show me how to add it to the existing function? I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

With moment.JS : viernes, 4 de mayo de 2018 22:33

```js
const $time = "Fri May 04 20:33:17 +0000 2018";

const myDate = new Date($time);
const myMoment = moment(myDate);

document.body.innerHTML = myMoment.format('LLLL');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/locale/es.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'd rather not use external ressources other than jQuery, but thanks.

Comment: @Meek You can write your own code yourself, Why do you wait someone write for you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date