# Date & Time conversion from 2018-05-29T04:12:35Z to something else

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to convert the date & time format i.e. 2018-05-29T04:12:35Z in the format like 1 hour ago or something like this.

Comment: What is the exact result you want from?

Comment: I want something like this......   12 mins ago  or 1 hour ago or 1 week ago accordingly..

Comment: Using [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) is recommended here. See [this section](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) specifically.

Comment: Is it possible?? Of course it is. A little bit of web searching would get you numerous approaches to get a good start point from

Comment: you need to calculate difference between current timestamp (Date.now()) and your given timestamp and then round it to the time units you need, hours in your example. Rounding can be greedy, so you round to the largest unit of time that fits inside the range.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format time since xxx e.g. “4 minutes ago” similar to Stack Exchange sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177836/how-to-format-time-since-xxx-e-g-4-minutes-ago-similar-to-stack-exchange-site)

Answer (score 0):

You can use momentjs for this

```
moment("2018-05-29T04:12:35Z").fromNow()      //an hour ago
```

See [this](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) for reference

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
 console.log(moment("2018-05-29T04:12:35Z").fromNow());
 console.log(moment(new Date()).fromNow());
 console.log(moment("2018-05-29T05:12:35Z").fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

and you can get more details  if you search [moment.js from now](https://www.google.com/search?ei=dt8MW7aMCNK_rQGgtamADw&q=moment%20js%20ago%20now&oq=moment%20js%20ago%20now&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1l10.5369.6368.0.6526.4.4.0.0.0.0.184.346.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.2.346...0i22i30k1.0.eVw40Bves1A) in google