# Add a time ago in comment React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a comment section and want to add the time after it get posted into the user interface. Like "some seconds ago", the same as we see on Instagram or Facebook.

In this image, I have highlighted to add the time section:
[image: time]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/27m9E.jpg image link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format time since xxx e.g. “4 minutes ago” similar to Stack Exchange sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177836/how-to-format-time-since-xxx-e-g-4-minutes-ago-similar-to-stack-exchange-site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add state in your comment component like timeSinceCommentCreation and on the instance when user post a comment, you need to update the state in componentWillUpdate equal to `moment().startOf('hour').fromNow()`. use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library which deals which is great to use time in your application

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to store the time when the comment is posted in the database. Like how you store comment content.

Second, in the front-end, you need to compare the posted time to the current time. If the difference is less than 60 seconds, show xx seconds ago, if above 60 seconds, you show xx minutes ago. Same for hours and days.