# How Do I Convert Timestamp to Number of Days in JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please  I received a response from a REST API, and in the JSON object, the time value was a timestamp. However, I need to render it as a "number of days" kind of format.

I received this particular time stamp: "2022-01-12T13:05:16Z"

I want to render it as something like "5 days ago"

How do I go about this please?

Comment: What did you try? What *didn't* you find when googleing this problem? Please see [ask].

Comment: Calculate how long ago it was, round it to days, and then display it.

Comment: Can you give a code example please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format time since xxx e.g. “4 minutes ago” similar to Stack Exchange sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177836/how-to-format-time-since-xxx-e-g-4-minutes-ago-similar-to-stack-exchange-site)

Comment: Also the built-in [Intl.RelativeTimeFormat.prototype.format()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/intl/relativetimeformat/format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transform the current date and the date you want to milliseconds with `.getTime()` then subtract it then split the result to milliseconds in a day and you get the number of days passed, Math.ceil to round the number up

```js
console.log(Math.ceil((new Date().getTime() - new Date("2022-01-12T13:05:16Z").getTime()) / 86400000))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this returned the number of days as you stated